# Return from multiple ruby forks

Tags: ruby, concurrency, return, fork

I have the following code

```
read, write = IO.pipe
count = {}
ARGV.each do |filename|
    fork do
        read.close
        write.write Marshal.dump(do_stuff(filename))
        write.close
    end
end
write.close
count = Marshal.load(read.read)
read.close
Process.waitall

printf(count)
```

which works for one fork but I  obviously want to achieve concurrency so I'd need to get the `count` hash from all the forks. However I've so far only been able to retrieve one hash from either of the forks. How can I return all of them?

Comment: Instead of using `read` and `write` as variable names, use something more indicative and that won't collide with method names. `read.read` and `write.write` are confusing. Typically we'd use something like `in` and `out` or `io_in` and `io_out`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Marshal.load` will only load the first dump, and ignore the rest. For example:

```
Marshal.load(Marshal.dump("one") + Marshal.dump("two"))     #=> "one"
```

Edit:

To fix this, you could write the data directly, instead of using `Marshal.dump`. How well that works depends on the data you're trying to send.

Alternatively, you can add padding/markers, something like so:

```
io_in, io_out = IO.pipe
ARGV.each do |filename|
  fork do
    io_in.close
    data = filename
    io_out.write(Marshal.dump(data) + "::::")
    io_out.close
  end
end
io_out.close

data = io_in.read
io_in.close

data = data.split("::::").map {|it| Marshal.load(it) }

Process.waitall

p(data)
```

I've tested the above to work in trivial cases, but I'm not sure how well it will handle anything going wrong.

Comment: Yeah, well I found out that much. How can I fix/circumvent that though?